# How to find a value within a substring within a string in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, search, substring

In VB.NET I need to find a value inside of a substring within a larger string.

For example, MyString is a string

```
MyString = "
============================
Channel      -->  36
Antenna      -->  127
MCS Level    -->  14
Bandwidth    -->  20
Packet Size  -->  4000
11N signal?  -->  1
BF Config    -->  0
============================"
```

If I need to find a particular value, say MCS level from that string, do I search for the location of "MCS Level    -->  " and find the value of the next 2 chars?

Or is there a way to search for "MCS Level    -->  %s" and find the value of %s within MyString?

Thanks! I appreciate the help. I want to do this properly.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular example, I would first split the string by new lines, then split each line again by whitespace (ignoring empty occurrences). That leaves you with a jagged array containing every piece of non-whitespace text per line.

```
Function GetMcsLevel(myString As String) As Integer
    For Each line As String In MyString.Split(Environment.NewLine)
        Dim pieces() As String = line.Split(New Char() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)   
        If pieces.First() = "MCS Level" Then
            Return Integer.Parse(pieces.Last())
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: So basically, that would spit out an array for each line {"MCS Level","-->","14"} and you're just returning the last value of the array? Great method, thanks!

Comment: Yep. It would still be much better if you could get the input data in XML or JSON format, because there are probably an infinite amount of ways to blow up code like this. Also beware that this function returns 0 even if "MCS Level" isn't in the input data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try regex as well. Check with this pattern:

```
MCS Level\D+(\d+)
```

It will give you the desired result `14`.

#### [Regex Demo](http://rubular.com/r/1ecgFFDLz2)

**EDIT**

**Sample Code:**  (*untested*, to give an idea)

```
Dim mcol as MatchCollection = System.Text.RegularExpression.Regex.Matches(MyString,"MCS Level\D+(\d+)")

for each m as match in mcol
   Debug.Print("MCS Level is : " & m.ToString())
Next
```